# Dark, fantasy animated movie where the antagonist is a tall humanoid with an eye patch, who fights the hero totally naked after his spaceship crashed

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm looking for a movie I saw at least 20 years ago (1998-2001).

I don't remember the story, I don't remember the main character. The only thing I know for sure is the villain was a tall humanoid with an animal looking like... a shark or something like that. He is strong and has grey skin.

At the end, I know this villain talks to the main character and MAYBE fights him. He is totally naked at this moment and both are in some kind of a desert with dark rock, as if they were in a dry ocean. I also remember there was, I THINK, a whale or something like that, dead, in the environment; there was some kind of *Death Stranding* ambience like that.

[image]

The rest of the movie has also a dark and mature ambience and story. I remember the story was too complex for me when I saw it.

Things that I'm not sure, but I THINK were true about the movie:

- I think it's a sci-fi movie.
- I think it's a Japanese animated movie, or at least a fantastic/dark fantasy one (due to this antagonist animal look).
- I think the antagonist had an eye-patch.
- I think in the rest of the movie, the antagonist has some kind of a uniform, like a captain or commander uniform.
- I think it's sci-fi because I think there're spaceships in this movie.
- I think the antagonist is naked at the end after his spaceship crashed, he also lost his eye-patch.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FullFrontalAssault

Comment: Ao no 6-gou (1998)? That one has the fish villain with a missing eye.

Comment: @Ocean YOU are a freakin' genius ! Thanks a lot, and I only see this now. This is definitely what I was looking for. Now comes the rewatch !

Answer (score 2):

This could be [Ao no 6-gou](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/1320,ao-no-6-gou/screenshots) (1998).

It has the mentioned ambience and a fish villain with a missing eye.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

could be a movie of the Space Pirate Captain Harlock franchise maybe

Comment: You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to specify a particular movie in the franchise, and explain why you think it might be the correct movie, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.